# Adding days to a given date in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a program that returns the dates after certain days.
Even though my code has no any sort of error, when I run it, the output dates are slightly off for some reason I have hard time figuring out.
Could you help fix my code?

For example) Input:

```
2018
1
1
```

should return:

```
100: 2018 04 10
200: 2018 07 19
300: 2018 10 27
```

but it doesn't....

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //declare variables
    int y,m,d;
    int yoon=0;//assume to be normal year at first

    //take user input
    cin>>y>>m>>d;

    //separate leap year & normal year (leap year: 1 , normal year = 0)
    if (y % 4 ==0){
        yoon = 1;
        if (y % 100 ==0) {
            yoon = 0;
            if (y % 400 == 0){
                yoon= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //iterate for 100, 200, 300 days
    for (int x=100;x<=300;x+=100) {
        //add days to the given date
        d+=100;
        //iterate untill there is no day overflow
        while(true)
        {
            //check the number of days in given month and subtract if it overflows
            if ((m == 4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11) && d>30)
            {
                d-=30;
                m++;
            }
            //different days for leap year
            else if (m==2 && d>29 && yoon ==1)
            {
                d-=29;
                m++;
            }
            //different days for normal year
            else if (m==2 && d>28 && yoon ==0)
            {
                d-=28;
                m++;
            }
            else if (d>31)
            {
                d-=31;
                m++;
                //check for leap year if the year changes
                if (m==13){
                    m=1;
                    y+=1;
                    if (y % 4 ==0){
                        yoon = 1;
                        if (y % 100 ==0) {
                            yoon = 0;
                            if (y % 400 == 0){
                                yoon= 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //output
        cout<<x<<":"<<" "<<y<<" ";
        if (m>0 && m<10){cout<<0;}
        cout<<m<<" ";
        if (d>0 && d<10){cout<<0;}
        cout<<d<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `. Even though my code has no any sort of error, when I run it, the output dates are slightly off for some reason.` I assume because it has an error.

Comment: *Even though my code has no any sort of error* -- Your program *compiled* and linked with no error.  That has nothing to do with whether your program has logical bugs or not.  If you were to write a program to add two numbers, but instead you subtracted those numbers, that program would have "no errors" also.  But does it work as intended?  No.

Comment: `std::chrono` should help

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date, which will be in a slightly modified form, in the c++20 standard.

Comment: Too much code and duplicated work. There should be exactly one place in your program that checks for leap year and make the appropriate adjustment. You have at least two places there. This is breeding ground for bugs. It's not worth salvaging the shown code, it needs to be rewritten from scratch after [a very long conversation with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: This is very simple with `mktime()`. It normalizes values so you just add in the days you want to `m_mdays` Why not just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's much room for improvement in your code, it does work as expected. You state that with input:

```
2018
1
1
```

you expect the output to be:

```
100: 2018 04 10
200: 2018 07 19
300: 2018 10 27
```

yet the output is:

```
100: 2018 04 11
200: 2018 07 20
300: 2018 10 28
```

This is correct since you entered 1 as the day and then add 100 to that every time inside your loop. Consequently, your code will return days 101, 201 and 301.

As for why you couldn't see that in your output, all calculations are done with `d`, yet your output uses `x` as the label, which *is* 100, 200 and 300 respectively.